# GWT Material Design - How to disable change data grid layout on mobile devices?

Tags: gwt, datagrid, material-design, gwt-material-design

I use GWT Material Design version 1.6.2. My data grid layout looks fine and I want to keep that layout on mobile devices.
So I don't want to see something like that in my application.

[image]

Any ideas how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: On version 2.0 of the GMD Table, we encourage you to make a midgration to it, as it brings a lot of improvements and fuctionality to the Table world on MaterialDesign as long as the GMD Project.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Just do not need to set css style "responsive-table" on data greed. 
For example change :

```
dataGrid.setStyleName("hoverable responsive-table");
```

to

```
dataGrid.setStyleName("hoverable");
```